# get the subplot from pick event

Tags: python, matplotlib, onclick, subplot

I have a figure with four subplots, two of which are binded on a pick event, by doing `canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)` where onpick is onpick(event) handler.

Now, based on which of the two suplot the click come in, I must activate a different behaviour (ie if pick come from 1st subplot do this, else if it come from second suplot do that), but I don't know how to do it.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a short example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import random

def onpick(event):
    if event.artist == plt1:
        print("Picked on top plot")
    elif event.artist == plt2:
        print("Picked on bottom plot")

first = [random()*i for i in range(10)]
second = [random()*i for i in range(10)]

fig = plt.figure(1)
plt1 = plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(range(10), first)

plt2 = plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(range(10), second)

plt1.set_picker(True)
plt2.set_picker(True)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

Note that you have to call `set_picker(True)` on the subplots that should fire this event! If you don't, nothing will happen even though you've set the event on the canvas.

For further reading, here's the [`PickEvent` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.PickEvent) and an [pick handling demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html) from the matplotlib site.

Comment: so the discriminant information I was searching for was in event.artist, thank you. You really solved my problem