# Change Color of Picked Data-Point inside a Subplot with a click

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, events

Good Day Stack-Overflow,

i am a relative python beginner and i am stuck with the following task: I would like to change the color of a Data Point by clinking on the point itself. I came relativly far by creating random subplots but i can change the color of the points just in the last subplot (clicking somewhere else will also change the color only in the last plot). What am I missing?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import sys


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
xlim = (0, 30)
ylim = (0, 15)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 15, 5))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 15, 5))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 30, 5))
plt.setp(axes, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)

for i in range(0, 5, 1):
    for j in range(0, 3, 1):
        X_t = np.random.rand(10, 4) * 20
        points = axes[i][j].scatter(X_t[:, 0], X_t[:, 1],
                                    facecolors=["C0"] * len(X_t), edgecolors=["C0"] * len(X_t), picker=True)


def onpick(event):
    print(X_t[event.ind], "clicked")
    points._facecolors[event.ind, :] = (1, 1, 0, 1)
    points._edgecolors[event.ind, :] = (1, 0, 0, 1)
    fig.canvas.draw()


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)


plt.show()
```

It seems that the information that is included in the event.ind is not right and I am asking for that information at the wrong moment.

I am happy about any help!

Greetings!

(Edits on suggested best practice)

Comment: `points` is overwritten at each iteration. It's not so much a surprise that you can operate on the last subplot only...

Comment: Hi @gboffi! Yes, I understand that points inside ```points``` there is always the last value. But how can i access the information on the point in that specific subplot?

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem in full, I just wanted to underline a possible misunderstanding (hence a comment and not an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save all the points for your different subplots and check via 
`event.artist` in which subplot you are clicking currently ([See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38568646/get-the-subplot-from-pick-event-with-matplotlib-and-python))

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
xlim = (0, 30)
ylim = (0, 15)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 15, 5))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 15, 5))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 30, 5))
plt.setp(axes, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)

points_list = []   ###
for i in range(0, 5, 1):
    for j in range(0, 3, 1):
        X_t = np.random.rand(10, 4) * 20
        points_list.append(axes[i][j].scatter(X_t[:, 0], X_t[:, 1],
                                              facecolors=["C0"] * len(X_t), edgecolors=["C0"] * len(X_t), picker=True))   ###


def onpick(event):
    print(event.artist, X_t[event.ind], "clicked")
    for points in points_list:
        if event.artist == points:  ###
            points._facecolors[event.ind, :] = (1, 1, 0, 1)
            points._edgecolors[event.ind, :] = (1, 0, 0, 1)

    fig.canvas.draw()


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
plt.show()
```

From the check `event.artist == points` you see, you could use `event.artist` directly instead of saving all the points in a list:

```
def onpick(event):
    print(event.artist, X_t[event.ind], "clicked")
    event.artist._facecolors[event.ind, :] = (1, 1, 0, 1)
    event.artist._edgecolors[event.ind, :] = (1, 0, 0, 1)
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Thanks! A list worked perfectly. I was trying to compute every point into a dictionary, but your solutions is more elegant.