# Picking on subplots - unable to extract metadata

Tags: python, matplotlib, onclick, event-handling, subplot

Apologies if I have some of the terminology wrong.

I am attempting to build a picker to allow me/ future users to slice a dataframe for a relatively large dataset (1000's of rows, 10's of cols).

Ideally, the goal will be to pass the x-coordinate of each subplot to a dictionary where dict.keys will be the subplot number e.g. 0 for the first, 1 for the second etc

An added complication is that I have varying numbers of subplots across different datasets so would like it to automatically assign these labels.

So far I have set up my "returned_points" as a nested list. Now, what I can do is pass "click" to this list (of lists) and have the string assigned to the correct index for the subplot. I can also pass point info to a "flat" list, one that does not tell me which subplot the points are from.

What I can't do is get the artist data - I mean the values of points in the plot I click on - to be passed to the correct list within the nested list.

I've been following examples from these questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047846/determine-button-clicked-subplot-in-matplotlib)
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38568646/get-the-subplot-from-pick-event-with-matplotlib-and-python) and the matplotlib demo [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html)

MWE:

```
def test1(event):
    for i in list(range(len(fig.axes))):
        if event.inaxes == fig.axes[i]:
            test[i].append("click")

def test2(event):
    for i in list(range(len(fig.axes))):
        if event.inaxes == fig.axes[i]:
            thisline = event.artist
            xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
            ind = event.ind
            vals[i].append(xdata[ind])

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)

test = [[] for i in fig.axes]
vals = [[] for i in fig.axes]

for ax in fig.axes:
    ax.plot(x, y, "o")
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event",test1)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event",test2)

print(test)
print(vals)
```

clicking four times in the top plot and once in the lower will return:

```
[['click', 'click', 'click', 'click'], ['click']] # passing a string works fine
[[], []] # getting the artist data to write to the list does not work...
```

The basic "flat" version:

```
def onpick(event):
    thisline = event.artist
    xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
    ind = event.ind
    picker_tmp.append(xdata[ind])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)

picker_tmp = []

for ax in fig.axes:
    ax.plot(x, y, "o", picker=True)

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

print(picker_tmp)
```

Gives:

```
[array([0.249527]), array([0.36171572]), array([0.47993459]), array([0.8400918]), array([0.4248754])] 

# getting artist data works fine here?!...
```

Comment: In `matplotlib 3.7.2`, `thisline = event.artist` results in `AttributeError: 'MouseEvent' object has no attribute 'artist'`.

Comment: [edit] the question to add updates

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TrentonMcKinney for pointing out the mistake. I mixed up "pick_event" and ""button_press_event". Not sure why "pick_event" does not work for this though.

Working code:

```
def test(event):
    for i in list(range(len(fig.axes))):
        if event.inaxes == fig.axes[i]:
            vals[i].append(round(float(event.xdata), 0))
            
x = np.random.rand(10)*10
y = np.random.rand(10)*10

fig, ax = plt.subplots(4,1)

vals = [[] for i in fig.axes]
    
for ax in fig.axes:
    ax.plot(x, y, "o", picker=True)
    
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',test)
```